# How to get not equal rows in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables and I want not equal rows to be fetched. How to write a query?

For example, `table a` contain 10 rows, `table b` contain 10 rows.
Equal rows in a and b is 5.

I want to take a not equal rows (not in b table)

How to fetch  a table value which is not equal to b table  ?

Result should be 5 record

Comment: minus is not giving correct answer . its give both table not equal value . I want only a table value

Answer (score 2):

To take rows in A but not in B:

```
select * from A minus select * from B
```

To take rows in A and B but not in both:

```
(select * from A union  select * from  B) minus (select * from A intersect select * from B)
```

Comment: minus is not giving correct answer . its give both table not equal value . I want only a table value

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved long ago. The optimal solution only reads each table once (unlike the "symmetric difference" solution which reads each table twice and does some additional work).

```
select 'A' as source, col1, col2, ...
from   table_A
union all
select 'B' as source, col1, col2, ...
from   table_B
group by col1, col2, ...
having count(*) = 1
;
```

If a row is present in both tables, then the count will be 2.

This assumes there are no duplicate rows in either table; if there may be duplicate rows, the HAVING condition can be modified, for example:

```
having count(case when source = 'A' then 1 end) = 0 
    or count(case when source = 'B' then 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

use EXCEPT

the syntax is similar to INTERSECT.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-intersect-clause.htm